# Can a RTSP pause request be supported while playing a live video stream?

Tags: rtsp

I wondered whether the `PAUSE` request of RTSP protocol can be supported while playing a live video stream.

For example, a real time video stream from a camera.

Comment: This could be achieved by buffering packets until the pause has ended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the RFC:

> 10.6 PAUSE
>
> The PAUSE request causes the stream delivery to be interrupted
>   (halted) temporarily. If the request URL names a stream, only
>   playback and recording of that stream is halted. For example, for
>   audio, this is equivalent to muting. If the request URL names a
>   presentation or group of streams, delivery of all currently active
>   streams within the presentation or group is halted. After resuming
>   playback or recording, synchronization of the tracks MUST be
>   maintained.

The specification does not say whether live stream pausing must or should be available. `PAUSE` makes sense for live streams in terms of temporarily not sending data. However it is up to server to support or not support this command. My guess is that few cameras implement it for live video - the options are either to receive and not display video, or disconnect and re-connect later.

Comment: Thanks. `After resuming
playback or recording, synchronization of the tracks MUST be
maintained.` -- How could a live video resume and synchronize the tracks?

Comment: This means, if you stream multiple tracks, their time stamping should remain in sync after resuming.

Comment: This could be achieved by buffering packets until the pause has ended.

Comment: The server has to stop() the encoder on pause, and start() on play. An ip-camera device driver would need to support this.